# Arzelà's bounded convergence theorem - proof for certain case.

Tags: analysis

The theorem is stated here: http://www.math.toronto.edu/lguth/acepabct.pdf as theorem 1.1. I know how the dominated convergence theorem proofs this but I haven't learnt that, Im particularly concerned with proving the theorem if the f=zero function and C=1. If tried to but to no success, any help will be very much appreciated.